# Getting a piece of VBA code that is in a Word document to run from an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word file that contains a working piece of VBA code that is activated from a button click. This VBA code has some dialog to ask users for file names and does some manipulations on data in these files. The code works just fine.

However, I now need to run this VBA code from a button click in Excel, still allowing the word VBA code to do its thing. That is, I just want the code in the Excel file to effectively emulate what the button click does now in the word file. It seems ok but the code below just does not execute the line Application.Run

```
' Make it compulsory to declare all variables

Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim oAPP As Object
    Dim chooseColumn As Variant

    Set oAPP = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    oAPP.Visible = True
    strFile = "Coding of Survey Answers.docm"
    
    'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable

        MsgBox " Select the file " & strFile
        
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        
'Makes sure the user can select only one file

        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        
        .Filters.Add "Word Files", "*.docx; *.doc; *.docm", 1
 'Show the dialog box
 
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "Error - could find the file " & strFile & " Retry"
            Else
        End If
         
 'Store in strFile variable
 
        strFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
  
    oAPP.Documents.Open Filename:=strFile
  
    Application.Run "CommandButton1_Click()"
   
    
   



' This is where the code for the Excel Part will have to go

' First Clear data in tables in this document

        'CodeFile = ActiveDocument.FullName
        'Documents.Open CodeFile
        'Documents(CodeFile).Activate
        'Tabnum = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        
    chooseColumn = InputBox("Into which Column to wish to past this data?")
    MsgBox chooseColumn
    
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does the sub to be called (`CommandButton1_Click`) exist? Is it in a .docm document? Is this the one you preliminarily open? If not, where is it?

Comment: Cross-posted at:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1338405/getting-a-piece-of-vba-code-in-a-word-document-to?comment=question#newest-question-comment
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the word object to run the module, not the Application.Run command. Application.Run is referring to excel, the application used, but you want to run a word app macro: so changed it to oAPP.run "CommandButton1_Click()"

```
'Make it compulsory to declare all variables

Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim oAPP As Object
    Dim chooseColumn As Variant

    Set oAPP = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    oAPP.Visible = True
    strFile = "Coding of Survey Answers.docm"
    
    'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable

        MsgBox " Select the file " & strFile
        
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        
'Makes sure the user can select only one file

        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        
        .Filters.Add "Word Files", "*.docx; *.doc; *.docm", 1
 'Show the dialog box
 
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "Error - could find the file " & strFile & " Retry"
            Else
        End If
         
 'Store in strFile variable
 
        strFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
  
    oAPP.Documents.Open Filename:=strFile
  
'CHANGED LINE HERE:
    oAPP.Run "CommandButton1_Click()"
   

' This is where the code for the Excel Part will have to go

' First Clear data in tables in this document

        'CodeFile = ActiveDocument.FullName
        'Documents.Open CodeFile
        'Documents(CodeFile).Activate
        'Tabnum = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        
    chooseColumn = InputBox("Into which Column to wish to past this data?")
    MsgBox chooseColumn
    
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer the clarification question... It was meant to configure the code to run a procedure from a specific document. There may exist more than one `CommandButton1` in different documents and you need to call the appropriate one. So, I will try showing a generic code able to search for the already Word open session, if it exists search between the open documents if the necessary one is open and open a new one and the necessary document if no any already open session. If you need running that sub many time, it would be inappropriate to open a new session each time you run it.

1.Usually a `CommandButton` code stays in `ThisDocument` code module, created as `Private Sub  CommandButton1_Click()`. You firstly **must make it `Public`**!

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '... whatever to be done...
End Sub
```

2. Call it from Excel in the next way:

```
Sub RunSubFromWord()
  Dim objW As Word.Application, d As Word.Document
  
  Const strDocMacro As String = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Word VBA\Test Word VBA.docm"

  On Error Resume Next
   Set objW = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'get the Word open session
   If err.number <> 0 Then 'if no any Word ope session:
     err.Clear
     Set objW = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'open a Word new session
     objW.Visible = True 'to see it and avoid remaining between the running processes...
     Set d = objW.Documents.Open(strDocMacro)    'open the document having the necessary macro
   End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  If d Is Nothing Then
    For Each d In objW.Documents 'identify the necessary doc, if already open
        If d.fullname = strDocMacro Then Exit For
    Next d

    If d Is Nothing Then _
       Set d = objW.Documents.Open(strDocMacro) 'if not already open, open it.
  End If
  
  'run the procedure existing on the NECESSARY document:
  objW.Run "'" & d.fullname & "'!ThisDocument.CommandButton1_click" 'it works...
End Sub
```